# Do other registries (Pypi, Maven, RubyGems...) have a fund option like npm?

Tags: maven, package, dependencies, repository, pypi

I'm researching how to detect insufficiently maintained projects. Npm fund could be one of the markers since it clearly states that the project needs funds. I cannot seem to find something similar for other registries, do you know if it exists? Also, if you know some other features or have ideas on how to spot these kinds of projects, it would be huge help.

Comment: This question does not seem really on topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Commit activity (for example by analyzing the GitHub commit history) is often a better indicator of sufficiently maintained projects.

Open source projects aren't looking for funding when they start out, nor after they figured out a sustainable open source business model (unless that business model is funding, which is rarely sustainable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, that's true. I already have several markers but I was trying to expand it as much as possible and this seemed as a nice idea if other repos have that option. I was thinking about projects that started perhaps as a smaller side project next to a regular job, so on a volunteer basis. But grew too much that the owner does not have time to maintain it well and thus, annotates that he needs funds to be able to invest more time in it.